# How to hold a microphone on a stand that is too small?

Tags: technology, sound

I have a microphone and stand. The microphone is too wide to fit into the holder at the top of the stand. What can I use to keep it securely held on the stand and still allow it to be picked up by its user?

Answer (score 3):

#### An actual solution from [this Lifehacker Article](http://lifehacker.com/215846/make-a-microphone-stand-out-of-a-wire-hanger)

This uses only a wire hanger

> "Just take a metal hanger, bend it in half a little, then bend the hook down and adjust as necessary. It's pretty stable, being what it is."

To attach this to a stand that you already have, you can cut off some of the wire and then attach the rest of it to the stand with glue or tape.

#### My made up solution

<sup>Disclaimer: I've never had this problem, this is something I made up</sup>

First get a piece of construction, or some other type of sturdy paper that can bend. Shape the construction paper into a cone and then put the microphone in. Allow a hole big enough for the back of the microphone to fit through. Then use scissors to cut off most of the construction paper, but not too much because you don't want the microphone to fall out. Then just use glue or tape to attach the paper in the holder if you can (just the back of the paper) or on top of the holder. Not sure how well this will work because I've never tried it before.

Answer (score 2):

Duct tape. Didn't you know duct tape solves all problems in the world? http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0286915/

[image]

Comment: I read the question again. I think duct tape would be difficult if you tape the microphone down, but, if the duct tape is applied sticky side up, you can just stick the microphone to the stand and it will stay there. You can pick the microphone back up. I think that would be a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Blue Tac.**

Blue Tac has featured in a few of my answers on this site and it is rearing its head once again as it would be an ideal solution to you problem.
Just get a nice blob of the stuff (or any other non permanent adhesive putty)  and put it on your mic stand and voila. When you put your microphone in the stand holder thing it should hold true due to the wonders of blue Tac.!